# Powershell regex match sequence doesn't work although it matches in Sublime Text find and replace

Tags: regex, git, powershell, sublimetext3, asciidoc

I am trying to create a Powershell regex statement to remove the top five lines of this output from a git diff file that has already been modified with Powershell regex.

```
[1mdiff --git a/uk1.adoc b/uk2.adoc</span>+++
[1mindex b5d3bf7..90299b8 100644</span>+++
[1m--- a/uk1.adoc</span>+++
[1m+++ b/uk2.adoc</span>+++
[36m@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@</span>+++
= Heading

Body text
```

[image: Image shown because binary code doesn't show in the text]

Image shown because binary code doesn't show in the text

The following statement matches the text so the '= Heading' line is placed at the top of the page if I replace with nothing.

```
^[^=]*.[+][\n]
```

[image]

But in Powershell, it isn't matching the text.

```
Get-Content "result2.adoc" | % { $_  -Replace '^[^=]*.[+][\n]', '' } | Out-File  "result3.adoc";
```

[image]

Any ideas about why it doesn't work in Powershell?

My overall goal is to create a diff file of two versions of an AsciiDoc file and then replace the ASCII codes with HTML/CSS code to display the resulting AsciiDoc file with green/red track changes.

Comment: Why is `0x1b` there? Is it in input string? I think `^[^=]*` suffices.

Comment: The `0x1b` is an Escape character (ASCII 27). Apparently Sublime Text shows its presence but in the PowerShell editor it is a hidden character. You need to watch out for these inserted characters when copy/pasting.

Comment: @Theo, by _PowerShell editor_ do you mean Visual Studio Code? The ISE? In Visual Studio Code you can make hidden-by-default control characters visible via `View > Toggle Control Characters`.

Comment: You're right @revo. I didn't need the  0x1b. Thanks.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, I meant the ISE. I know that other editors may have the ability to show these characters, but as far as I know not the ISE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest - and faster - approach is to read the input file as a *single, multiline* string with `Get-Content -Raw` and let the regex passed to `-replace` operate across multiple lines:

```
(Get-Content -Raw result2.adoc) -replace '(?s)^.+?\n(?==)' |
  Set-Content result3.adoc
```

- `(?s)` activates in-line option `s` which makes `.` match newline (`\n`) characters too.
- `^.+?\n(?==)` matches from the start of the string (`^`) any number of characters (including newlines) (`.+`), non-greedily (`?`)
- until a newline (`\n`) followed by a `=` is found.

  - `(?=...)` is a look-ahead assertion, which matches `=` without *consuming* it, i.e., without considering it part of the substring that matched.

Since no replacement operand is passed to `-replace`, the entire match is replace with the implied *empty string*, i.e., what was matched is effectively *removed*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The `-replace` operator passes its LHS *through* if no match is found, so you cannot use it to *filter out* non-matching lines.

Even if you match an undesired line in full and replace it with `''` (the empty string), it will show up as an *empty line* in the output when sent to `Set-Content` or `Out-File` (`>`).

As for your specific regex, `^[^=]*.[+][\n]` (whether or not the first `^` is followed by an ESC (`0x1b`) char.):

- `[\n]` (just `\n` would suffice) tries to match a newline char. after a literal `+` (`[+]`), yet lines read individually with `Get-Content` (without `-Raw`)  by definition are *stripped* of their trailing newline, so the `\n` will never match; instead, use `$` to match the end of a line.

---

Instead of `%` (the built-in alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet) you could have used `?` (the built-in alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet) to perform the desired filtering:

```
Get-Content result2.adoc | ? { $_ -notmatch '^\e\[' }
```

`$_ -notmatch '^\e['` returns `$True` only for lines that don't start (`^`) with an ESC character (`\e`, whose code point is `0x1b`) followed by a literal (`\`) `[`, thereby effectively filtering out the lines before the `= Heading` line.

However, the multi-line `-replace` command at the top is a more direct and faster expression of your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I ended up with after help from @mklement0. This Powershell script creates MS Word-style track changes for two versions of an AsciiDoc file. It creates the Diff file, uses regex to replace ASCII codes with HTML/CSS tags, removes the Diff header (thank you!), uses AsciiDoctor to create an HTML file and then PrinceXML to create a PDF file of the output that I can send to document reviewers.

```
    git diff --color-words file1.adoc file2.adoc > result.adoc;
Get-Content "result.adoc" | % {
$_  -Replace '(=+ ?)([A-Za-z\s]+)(\[m)', '$1$2' `
    -Replace '\[32m', '+++<span style="color: #00cd00;">' `
    -Replace '\[31m', '+++<span style="color: #cd0000; text-decoration: line-through;">' `
    -Replace '\[m', '</span>+++' } | Out-File -encoding utf8 "result2.adoc" ;
(Get-Content -Raw result2.adoc) -replace '(?s)^.+?\n(?==)', '' | Out-File -encoding utf8 "result3.adoc" ;
asciidoctor result3.adoc -o result3.html;
prince result3.html --javascript -o result3.pdf;
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Here's a screenshot of the result using some text from Wikipedia:

[image]